# Javascript Regex - 9 chars long, starting with 'SO-' and ending with 6 numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

Regular expressions are simply evil in my mind and no matter how many times I read any documentation I just cannot seem to grasp even the simplest of expressions!

I am trying to write what must be a very simple expression to query a variable in javascript but I just cannot get it to work properly.

I am trying to validate the following:-

The string must be 9 characters long, starting with SO- (case insensitive eg So-, so-, sO- and SO-) followed by 6 numbers.

So the following should all match

SO-123456,
So-123456,
sO-456789,
so-789123

but the following should fail

SO-12d456,
SO-1234567

etc etc

I have only managed to get this far so far

```
var _reg = /(SO-)\d{6}/i;

var _tests = new Array();
_tests[0] = "So-123456";
_tests[1] = "SO-123456";
_tests[2] = "sO-456789";
_tests[3] = "so-789123";
_tests[4] = "QR-123456";
_tests[5] = "SO-1234567";
_tests[6] = "SO-45k789";

for(var i = 0; i < _tests.length; i++){
  var _matches = _tests[i].match(_reg);
  if(_matches && _matches.length > 0)
     $('#matches').append(i+'. '+_matches[0] + '<br/>');
}
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/TzHKd/ for above example

Test number 5 is matching although it should fail as there are 7 numbers and not 6.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Add starting (`^`) and ending (`$`) anchors to your expression.

Comment: +1 for actually giving the regex a go. Many regex questions on Stack Overflow are simply "give me teh codez".

Comment: @matt it's still not a useful question for the site - there are already enough duplicates

Comment: @JanDvorak Given that you do not realize that the regex matched within and you needed anchors, what would you expect to be the search term? Many times the best search requires the OP to know the terminology, likely from another answer.

Comment: @hex did I say the question was _bad_? I only implied it was not worth an upvote IMO. As for the search terms - the exact question title should already reveal something, and also any decent regex tutorial - as well as the `RegExp` MDN page - should mention string anchors soon enough.

Comment: @JanDvorak I did not say that you were saying the question was bad. I was simply stating that it cannot be discredited based on its duplicity.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not useful for the site - it was definitely useful for me. I had looked around for quite some time and as I said in the question reading regex examples and the documentation confuses the heck out of me.  As you could see from my question I did actually try quite a few things and tried to be as un-annoying as possible with the question and the title hence why I posted what I had tried. I am not a coder rather a jack of all trades when it comes to IT so being an expert in all areas is just simply not possible. However, if it annoys people then please remove the +1's :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this regexp instead

```
/^(so-)\d{6}$/i;
```

without `^` (string *starting* with) or `$` (string *ending* with) you're looking for a generic substring match (that's the reason why when you have 7 digits your regexp return true).

Comment: just mantained the original parens, maybe he needs to have them.

Comment: I said that, based on how the regex is used in the code snippet. It seems that it is only used for validation.

Comment: then he could remove the parens from the regexp :)

Comment: Many thanks for the fast answer.  Helped me enormously - I was pulling my hair out.  I have now been able to make my other 5 regex's now that I know how to do it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

By using the anchors `^` and `$` (matching beginining of line and end of line respectively), you can make the regex match the whole line. Otherwise, the match with return true as soon as the characters in the regex are matched.

So, you will apply it like this:

```
var _reg = /^(so-)\d{6}$/i;
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response - much appreciated.  @fabrizio-calderan beat it by 2 minutes though from what I can see so I will accept his answer.  But thank you once again :-)

Comment: @l0ckm4 It's fine with me, don't worry :) There was only the piece of code initially in his so I added the explanation, but then the edit came ^^;